# Add column in view - Last matching condition using MySQL Below v8

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to SELECT the last element's column value which is matching a condition and add it in a view using MySQL.

Consider I have the following

Table1:

```
id    created_at    value
1     2019-03-18    24
2     2019-03-19    50
3     2016-03-20    100
4     2016-03-21    87
5     2016-03-22    105
6     2016-03-23    109
7     2016-03-24    100
8     2016-03-25    90
9     2016-03-26    104
10    2016-03-27    108
11    2016-03-28    80
```

Table2:

```
id    created_at    value
1     2019-03-18    18
2     2016-03-21    1024
3     2016-03-27    554
```

I have been searching on google and trying different queries without success for now...

I am trying to add a custom column on a view. This column is the last "value" field from table2 where the date is less or equal to the created_at from table1.

The output view should look like that:

```
id    created_at    value    output
1     2019-03-18    24       18
2     2019-03-19    50       18
3     2016-03-20    100      18
4     2016-03-21    87       1024
5     2016-03-22    105      1024
6     2016-03-23    109      1024
7     2016-03-24    100      1024
8     2016-03-25    90       1024
9     2016-03-26    104      1024
9     2016-03-27    108      554
9     2016-03-28    80       554
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would often be approached using a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.value
        from t2
        where t2.created_at <= t1.created_at
        order by t2.created_at desc
        limit 1
       ) as output
from t1;
```

On a large amount of data, this is not going to be efficient, although an index on `t2(created_at, value)`, might help a bit.

It is tricky to optimize a query like this on a large amount of data.  If that is the issue, ask a *new* question and be very clear about the data sizes and the version of MySQL that you are using.

Comment: This works fine. I was trying to avoid the double imbricate SELECT but I guess I have no choice as the version is below 8.0

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL 8+ solution, using `LEAD`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, created_at, value,
        LEAD(created_at) OVER (ORDER BY created_at) next_created_at
    FROM Table2
)

SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.created_at,
    t1.value,
    t2.value AS output
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.created_at >= t2.created_at AND
       (t1.created_at < t2.next_created_at OR t2.next_created_at IS NULL)
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry but I am using MySQL -8 version. Meaning I can't use WITH. Does it mean I will need to use a double imbricate SELECT instead?

Comment: You would have to replace the CTE logic with another way to find the lead.

Comment: Let me edit the post so people knows it is below MySql 8 version.